# Laravel change relationship where clause if not rows are returned

Tags: php, eloquent, distinct, query-builder

I have the following query in my controller.

```
$items = Item::with(['subitems' => function($query) {
    $query->where('language_id', '=', 1);
}])->get();
```

This is correctly getting me all items including subitems that have a language id of 1.

There are two things I would like to do with this though

- Firstly, I need to return all subitems that have a distinct 'ref_id' value.
- Secondly, I would like to give preference to the language id `1` but if none exist, use any language id.

So for example, I know this code won't work, but the sort of thing I am looking for is:

```
$items = Item::with(['subitems' => function($query) {
    $subItems = $query->where('language_id', '=', 1)
        ->where('ref_id', 'is', 'distinct');

    if($subItems->count() <= 0) {
      $subItems = $query->where('ref_id', 'is', 'distinct');
    }
}])->get();
```

Is this possible or is it a bit too complicated for Query Builder?  Even if one of the two requests was possible, that would be great.

Comment: What do you mean by "have a distinct 'ref_id' value"? Return one subitem per `ref_id` value?

Comment: yes, that is right. So if there are more than one subItems with the same ref_id, the first one is used and the rest are ignored.   Sorry, reading back through my question, that wasn't clear

Comment: What is the first one? The one with the lowest `id`?

Comment: It doesn't matter. Just the first one returned would do.  So if I were doing this physically, I would get all subItems. I would then split the subItems into groups, one group for each ref_id. Then from each group I would keep the first subItem that has a language id of 1. If there isn't one, I would just keep the first subItem irrespective of language id and bin the rest. Ultimately, I would have a list of subItems. Each subItem will have a unique ref_id and preferably have a language id of 1, but not mandatory.  Does that make sense? I think this may be too complicated with a single query.

Comment: Do you always want the `language_id` to be `1`? Or is this just an example value?

Comment: Yes. 1 will always be the preference. If no items exist with a value of 1 then it doesn’t matter what the language ID is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$items = Item::with(['subitems' => function($query) {
    $join = Subitem::select('ref_id', DB::raw('MIN(language_id) language_id'))
        ->groupBy('ref_id');
    $sql = '(' . $join->toSql() . ') subitems_distinct';
    $query->join(DB::raw($sql), function($join) {
        $join->on('subitems.ref_id', 'subitems_distinct.ref_id')
            ->on('subitems.language_id', 'subitems_distinct.language_id');
    });
}])->get();
```

We can use the fact that your preferred `language_id` is the lowest value and select the minimum.

Comment: That worked great. Thanks for your help despite the ambiguous question.